# Pino doesn`t save log with log level `debug` into mongo

Tags: nest, pino

I override methods ('info', 'debug', 'error') of console to save logs in db, but when I try to save
log with level 'debug', it isn`t saved.

Pino config:

```
import { pino } from 'pino';

export const getPinoLogger = (connectionMongoString) => {
  const transport = pino.transport({
    target: 'pino-mongodb',
    options: {
      uri: connectionMongoString,
      database: 'my_db',
      collection: 'my_collection',
    },
    levels: null
  });

  return pino(
    {
      base: null,
      timestamp: false,
      formatters: {
        level: (label) => {
          return { level: label };
        }
      }
    },
    transport
  );
};
```

Code of overriding methods of console

```
  ['info', 'error', 'debug'].forEach((methodName) => {
    console[methodName] = (...args) => {
      const pinoLogger = getPinoLogger(configService.get<string>('connection_string'));
      try {
        throw new Error();
      } catch(ex) {
        const callPlace = parse(ex.stack)[1];
        const logObject = {
          message: (args[0] ?? '') + ` (${callPlace?.methodName} at ${callPlace?.lineNumber})`,
          timestamp: Date.now(),
          userName: '',
        };
        
        switch (methodName) {
          case 'info':
            Logger.log(args[0]);
            pinoLogger.info(logObject);
            break;

          case 'error':
            Logger.error(args[0]);
            pinoLogger.error(logObject);
            break;
          
          case 'debug':
            Logger.debug(args[0]);
            pinoLogger.debug(logObject)
            
            break;
          }
        }
      };
    });
```

I`ve tried to set level 'trace' to save any logs, but it hasn`t helped me.
const transport = pino.transport({
target: 'pino-mongodb',
options: {
uri: connectionMongoString,
database: 'my_db',
collection: 'my_collection',
level: 'trace'
},
levels: null
});